# Getting Printing issue in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, printing, window, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to print windows forms and it is printing well but the issue is I want to print the form to the whole page. As you guys can see the the end of the page is empty. Is there a way to stretch is or something as solution. I'm new to C# and windows forms and don't know much, kindly anyone help !!. Explanation which is easy to understand.

[image]

here is my code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)

{
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            
            
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
            Graphics grp = panel.CreateGraphics();
            Size formSize = this.ClientSize;
            bitmap = new Bitmap(formSize.Width, formSize.Height, grp);
            grp = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            Point panelLocation = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
            grp.CopyFromScreen(panelLocation.X, panelLocation.Y, 0, 0, formSize);
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();


            
        }
        Bitmap bitmap;
        private void CaptureScreen()
        {
            Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            Size s = this.Size;
            bitmap = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
        }
```